# R mapping equivalent?

Tags: regex, r

Must be a way to avoid doing this in R. Some kind of mapping function? Basically, want to specify a series of grepl conditions and a series of replacements. Thanks,

```
hold[grepl('TRAVEL', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "TRAVEL"
hold[grepl('IN-KIND:', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "IN-KIND"
hold[grepl('COMPLIANCE', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "COMPLIANCE"
hold[grepl('MEDIA', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "MEDIA"
hold[grepl('WATER|FOOD|OFFICE|Office|CLEANING|ALARM', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "OFFICE"
hold[grepl('DATA', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "DATA"
hold[grepl('LEGAL', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "LEGAL"
hold[grepl('EVENT', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "EVENT"
hold[grepl('CATERING', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "CATERING"
hold[grepl('PHONE', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "PHONE"
hold[grepl('EQUIPMENT', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "EQUIPMENT"
hold[grepl('FUNDRAISING|FINANCE', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "FUNDRAISING"
hold[grepl('PAYROLL', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "PAYROLL"
hold[grepl('LIST RENTAL', hold[, "exp_pur_desc"]), "exp_pur_desc"] <- "LIST RENTAL"
```

Edit: Yeah, sorry, little flippant. hold is data.frame with one column named "exp_pur_desc." I can see lapply or sapply working with a "switch" equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `do.call` and/or `lapply` but your code isn't reproducible so it remains a guess as we have no idea what hold is.

Comment: Why don't you build toy source and target datasets with only a couple of these columns. Then you should say what the correct answer would be.

Comment: It seems like you are replacing 'TRAVEL' with 'TRAVEL' etc for many of the lines which seems redundant - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
strReplace <- function(x, mapFrom, mapTo) {
    for (i in seq_along(mapFrom)) {
        x <- gsub(mapFrom[[i]], mapTo[[i]], x)
    }
    x
}

strReplace(c("Hello cruel world!", "Hello again Tellus!"), # Text
           c("Hello", "world|Tellus"), # words to replace (regular expressions)
           c("Hi", "moon"))            # words to replace with
#[1] "Hi cruel moon!" "Hi again moon!"
```

... so in your case:

```
hold<-data.frame(ID=11:12, exp_pur_desc=c('FOOD','FINANCE'))
hold[['exp_pur_desc']] <- strReplace(hold[['exp_pur_desc']],
  c('WATER|FOOD|OFFICE|Office|CLEANING|ALARM', 'FUNDRAISING|FINANCE'),
  c('OFFICE', 'FUNDRAISING'))
hold
```

Comment: +1. Also, since the OP mentions a "map", I would find quite elegant to put the patterns and substitutions into a two-column data.frame before calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that uses the `gsubfn` package, this will replace any word with an "A" with just the "A", the same for "E", any with an "I","O", or "U" will be replaced by "IOU" and any lower case vowel will use "other" for the replacement (this replaces the whole string, which seems to be what is asked for, it can be modified if something else is desired):

```
library(gsubfn)

replacements <- list(A='A', E='E', I='IOU', O='IOU', U='IOU', 'other')

gsubfn('^.*?(A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u).*$', replacements, state.name)
```